# How to prove that there exists a countable subfield of real numbers which is mapped into itself for any function f?

Tags: functions, field-theory

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, how should I go about proving that there exists a **countable subfield** of $\mathbb{R}$, say $K$, which is mapped into itself? i.e., $f(K)\subset K$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is $R$ the real numbers. How arbitrary is $f$? (A constant function would be counterexample)

Comment: Mark, thank you for your reply. Yes, R is the set of real numbers. The function's completely arbitrary. Let's assume f is constant and equal to c, then $K={0,1,-1,nc,-nc,n/c, c^n,c^{-n}}$ is a subfield which satisfies the conditions. This is not a subfield but you know what I mean.

Comment: Let $K_0$ be the rationals. Let $K_1$ be the smallest subfield of the reals field that contains $f(K_0)$. Let $K_2$ be the smallest subfield of the reals that contains $f(K_1)$, and so on. Let $K$ be the union of the $K_n$.

Comment: Your answer would be great if we were certain that each of the proposed subfields is countable. How do we know this?

Comment: The image of a countable set under $f$ is countable. The smallest subfield of the reals that contains a given countable set is countable. And a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know the second fact that the smallest subfield containing a countable set is countable. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K_0$ be the field of rationals. For any $n\ge 0$, let $K_{n+1}$ be the intersection of all the subfields of the reals that contain $f(K_n)$. Finally, let $K$ be the union of all the $K_n$.

Note that $K$ is closed under $f$. For if $a\in K$, then $a\in K_n$ for some $n$, and therefore $f(a)\in K_{n+1}$.

For countability, note that each $K_n$ is countable. This can be done by induction. If $K_{n-1}$ is countable, then $f(K_{n-1})$ is countable. And for any countable set $A$, the smallest subfield $F$ of the reals that contains $A$ is countable. This is because any element of $F$ is of the shape $\frac{P(b_1,\dots,b_s)}{Q(c_1,\dots,c_t)}$, where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials with integer coefficients, and the $b_i,c_i$ are elements of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the subfield generated by $\{f^n(1)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\cup\{1\}$, where $f^n$ is the $n$-fold composition of $f$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more how we can generate a subfield using $\{f^n(1)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and why it is guaranteed that it is countable? Thank you.

Comment: Generating means take the smallest field containing these elements.  If you generate on a single element, you get a countable subfield.  Because you are generating on countable elements, I suspect that it will still be countable.

Comment: I think we need to go up to a field at each step of the iteration, to ensure closure under $f$.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, anyway, because the field is a quotient of the union of words in its generators and their inverses of each finite length $n$-so given a countable generating set one takes a union of countably many countable sets.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You're right.  I think my argument would work for $f$ a homomorphism.